# Maximum number of outgoing VPN connections?

Tags: windows, vpn

I'm working on a project where we would like to have around 50 outgoing (not incoming) VPN connections. We could use PPTP or IPSEC. Security isn't an issue, we control all the sites and users won't have access.
Windows Server appears to have a limit of 5 outgoing connections. Does anyone know if it's possible to tweak it to allow more? Or can we get this many outgoing VPN connections with Linux?

Comment: How did you figure the limit of 5 outgoing connections?

Comment: I saw it on the internet, so it must be true... I tested it on 2003 Server as well and five is the limit for PPTP. XP will only allow 2 outgoing connections. The fact that there is a difference between XP and Server gives me hope that there might be a tweak that will allow more.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenVPN running on Linux I have a system with about 30 connections typically open a time.